# How to set the color and the position of hyperlinks underline?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styling, underline

Is there any solution for setting both the color **and** the vertical position of hyperlinks underline that meets all these conditions?

1. works in modern browsers,
2. requires **pure CSS** (without adding HTML elements or JavaScript),
3. works also in cases when a link breaks into several lines (this is the main drawback of most solutions I know),
4. works irrespective of what `display` value the hyperlink has (`inline`, `block`, `inline-block` or more elaborate).

I have looked through all Q&A but every solution that I have found fails by one or more of these criteria.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the underline, you may add border to your "a" elements.

```
 a{
      text-decoration: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #yourcolor;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the vertical position of underline cannot be set this way. (E.g. moving the underline closer to text or making strike-through.)

Answer (score 0):

I always use pseudo classes `:before` and `:after` for this

I fear the solution I suggest also fails the requirement of multiple line links; but you are kind of vage here. Do you want it to be underlined once or the whole link in each line? (I think latter doesnt look sweet)

Only premises for this technique: 
element must be any other position than static
element needs either `:before` or `:after`

Watch here:
http://codepen.io/katerlouis/pen/xOWPRG

```
a {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -5px; 
        left: 0; right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        width: 60%; height: 2px;
        background: red;
    }
    &:hover:before {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, the main case of multiple lines is [like this](http://content.screencast.com/users/z1011001010111010010/folders/Default/media/738fc955-4411-4ec3-8ccf-94241481cc8b/07.21.2016-13.56.png). I definitely want such inline links to be underlined properly.

Comment: Isn't your example of line-breaking only possible with inline elements? When you make it an inline-block it would wrap this way, right? So watch my pen again: http://codepen.io/katerlouis/pen/xOWPRG